# 'UILabel?' does not have a member named 'text'

Tags: ios, swift, list, option-type

This is the code for a To Do list app I am trying to create:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var ToDoItems = ["Buy Groceries", "Pickup Laundry", "Wash Car", "Return Library Books", "Complete Assignment"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "ToDoCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = ToDoItems[indexPath.row] //This is where the issue is

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It does not help to just add boilerplate code the the question. The only method that has your code in it is the last one. The other methods contribute noting to the question.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the issue is that `UILabel?` is an optional (as indicated by the `?`). Fortunately, Xcode 6.4 has replaced this poorly worded error message with something far more clear: "value of optional type 'UILabel?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?". You might want to consider upgrading to Xcode 6.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safe way to do it is with an optional binding:

```
if let label = cell.textLabel {
    label.text = ToDoItems[indexPath.row]
}
```

Or you could use optional chaining:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = ToDoItems[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: How come the first option is better than the same one shorter option?

Comment: The answer above at first used a force unwrap, but then it was edited to be optional chaining instead.  I was referring to that.  Both of the methods I wrote are equally safe.

Comment: Sure they both safe. There are many other options to write the same unwrapping and make it safe. For example you can use switch and .Some and .Empty :)))

Comment: It's .Some and .None, not .Empty.  Check out my gist to see them all:
https://gist.github.com/patricklynch/689525d466c4ada42b8e

Comment: i tried both of these out, with the first one i got this error message:

Cannot assign 'let' value 'label'

Second one gives me no errors but when I run, the app does not show the expected results (It should show the ToDoItems in individual cells)

Comment: Make sure you're assigning to `label.text` and not `label`.  And if `cell.textLabel` is nil, nothing will happen, so make sure it is defined first.

Comment: Nice joke Patrick with all the options :))) I think you answer should be accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to unwrap label from Optional before use it.

```
cell.textLabel?.text = ToDoItems[indexPath.row]
```